# change the timestamp to UTC format in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, utc, timestamp-with-timezone

The question is kind of similar with the problem: [Change the timestamp to UTC format in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434538/change-the-timestamp-to-utc-format-in-pyspark?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Basically, it is convert timestamp string format ISO8601 with offset to UTC timestamp string(`2017-08-01T14:30:00+05:30` -> `2017-08-01T09:00:00+00:00` ) using **scala**.

I am kind of new to scala/java, I checked spark library which they dont have a way to convert without knowing the timezone, which I dont have a idea of timezone unless (I parse it in ugly way or using java/scala lib?) Can someone help?

UPDATE: The better way to do this: setup timezone session in spark, and use `df.cast(DataTypes.TimestampType)` to do the timezone shift

Comment: can you clarify with input and expected formats and also update with what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `java.time` primitives to parse and convert your timestamp.

```
scala> import java.time.{OffsetDateTime, ZoneOffset}
import java.time.{OffsetDateTime, ZoneOffset}

scala> val datetime = "2017-08-01T14:30:00+05:30"
datetime: String = 2017-08-01T14:30:00+05:30

scala> OffsetDateTime.parse(datetime).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
res44: java.time.OffsetDateTime = 2017-08-01T09:00Z
```

Comment: hi sir,I have the same question but I have a timestamp column in dataframe? How can I do the same conversion in a column

Comment: @experiment, I had this same question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182370/converting-timestamp-to-utc-in-spak-scala

Answer (score 3):

[`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_utc_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@to_utc_timestamp(ts:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,tz:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

> ```
> def to_utc_timestamp(ts: Column, tz: String): Column
> ```
>
> Given a timestamp like '2017-07-14 02:40:00.0', interprets it as a time in the given time zone, and renders that time as a timestamp in UTC. For example, 'GMT+1' would yield '2017-07-14 01:40:00.0'.

Comment: I don't have timezone explicitly from the string, whereas `to_utc_timestamp` needs to know timezone beforehand.